# mysql request not returning what is wanted

Tags: php, mysql, select, phpmyadmin

I am having troubles with a request in mysql... First of all my table have the following entries :

[image]

I am trying to guess why Forum des Halles, niveau - 4, rue l\'Orient-Express is a duplicate
I have tried the following mysql request :

```
SELECT * FROM geocode where initial_req LIKE '%Forum des Halles, niveau - 4, rue l\'Orient-Express%'
```

no result

```
SELECT * FROM geocode where initial_req LIKE "%Forum des Halles, niveau - 4, rue l\'Orient-Express%"
```

no result

```
SELECT * FROM geocode where initial_req LIKE "%Forum des Halles, niveau - 4, rue l'Orient-Express%"
```

no result

```
SELECT * FROM geocode where initial_req LIKE "%l\'Orient%"
```

no result

```
SELECT * FROM geocode where initial_req LIKE "%l\'%"
```

no result

```
SELECT * FROM geocode where initial_req LIKE "%\'Orient%"
```

2 results !!!

I don't understand why ! The print is exactly the same and it seems that l\' ain't working hile \'Orient is working. I am really perplex on what is going on... Can you help me ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM geocode where initial_req LIKE "%l\\\'Orient%" not returning too

Comment: How can we tell you why you have duplicated data in your table?

Comment: SELECT *
FROM `geocode`
WHERE `initial_req` LIKE '%Forum des Halles, niveau - 4, rue l\\\\\\''Orient-Express%' is returning 2 rows but why that's a mystery for me

Comment: @Arthur it is row id 7 and 21

Comment: What happens if you set initial_req to be UNIQUE?

Answer (score 0):

Your string is:

> ...rue l\'Orient...   (contains 2 special chars that must be escaped in a query)

to match it with LIKE you must use:

> '%\\\'Orient%'

since **\** must be escaped you must use **\\** and apostrophe is a special char that must be escaped too so **'** must be expressed as **\'**.

That's all.

So except your last query your patterns match **l'Orient** (and you do not have such thing in your table) but you must match **l\'Orient**

...and your last query matches **'Orient** hence it works.

BTW: Remember that this string I gave you it to be pasted into Mysql prompt - if used from PHP, Java code etc - you must pay attention to string escaping in these langs too so you may need more backslashes than shown here (twice as many - hence you say that 6 backslashes work for you - so it is within a code).

To ensure your query looks like mine - in PHP - just print it - it will show you that your backslash count is 2x less ans this amount will be in actual query - not what you see in your PHP code.

Of course - if you use any mysql/mysqli escaping routines it will be different ;-) and it all must be taken into account.

[read MYSQL string literals and escaping special chars](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html)

**Sumary:**

It is different story if you type in your query in mysql console, different if embedded within string in PHP, diferent fi using escape routines or not. Start from mysql prompt and adjust in your PHP if working.

Comment: yes I know and I apologize that among all request I forgot this one : SELECT * FROM geocode where initial_req LIKE "%\\\'Orient%" which returns no result too, the only one that is working is the following one SELECT * FROM geocode where initial_req LIKE "%\\\\\\''Orient%"

Comment: The picture is too small - is that double quote before Orient or an apostrophe?